# VSCode: Reopen windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I restore previous state if I open a file from command line. VSCode is closed before it.

I found similar questions

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15949
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/207
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34529

I have such setting `window.restoreWindows=all`

```
"all"
(default value) Reopen all windows unless a folder, workspace or file is opened (e.g. from the command line).
```

But when I type in command line
`code some.txt`  my previous open workspace gets lost

Added (01.02.2024)
Tried it on MacOS

1. Launch VS Code by itself: All previously open files are restored (my last workspace).
2. When VS Code is already launched, open a file (from command line): file is added as an editor/tab in current workspace.
3. Launch VS code by opening a file from command line: a fresh instance is created with only that file and any unsaved files; "clean" previous files/folders are not restored.

Comment: what do you want restored? if it's just a file(s), there's no workspace as far as I know. scroll position?  undo history?

Comment: @starball I want to restore my last workspace and one file in new tab. Now VSCode just opens with one tab

Comment: show an example commandline you are using.

Comment: @starballI added some info to original post

Comment: please give exact, complete steps on how to reproduce this. down to the detail of what the commands are, what file to edit, etc. a [mre]. I still don't have a clear understanding of what you are observing. show me exactly how I can minimally reproduce it.

Comment: close vsode . and type in terminal `code some.file.txt`

Comment: no. I need instructions to set up the workspace state ask well.